# git - merge changes without pull request

Tags: github, pull-request

I've forked a repo of another user on Github and I made a lot of changes on it.
Now the original owner said me that he would merge my changes in his repo.
I asked him if I should create a pull request, but he said no and he'll update his repo based on my branch.

Now I ask:
**are my changes counted on my contributions panel?**

The changes should go in to master branch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your commits has your contribution in your branch which will be merged. Than the answer to your questions is **YES** Otherwise, No